# How to implement callbacks on AWS RDS PostgreSQL using node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, callback

I'm trying to implement a call back on NodeJS EC2 server that's interacting with AWS RDS Postgresql. I'm not quite sure how it's done. There seems to be a EventEmitter method within AWS-SDK's RDS module. It's designed for all RDS instance types like MySQL, Aurora, etc. Not specifically for postgres. All I'm trying to do is to get some kind of callback after an INSERT or DELETE query.

Comment: What's wrong with simply executing the query and getting data as usual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not specific if your postgres is RDS or standalone on EC2.
You will need

`var pg = require('pg');
var dbe={"result":null};`

```
function Q(sqlQuery,callback) {
    /* async, vulnerable, simple */
    var conString = "postgres://"+dbUser+":"+dbPass+"@"+dbHost+":"+dbPort+"/"+dbName+"?ssl=true";
    pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {
      if(err) {
        return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
      }
      client.query(sqlQuery, function(err, result) {
        done();//call `done()` to release the client back to the pool
        if(err) {
          return console.error('error running query', err);
        }
        dbe.result = result;
        //console.log(JSON.parse(result.setEncoding('utf8');));
        callback();
      });
    });
}
```

And calling

`var res = Q('select now()', function(a) {console.log(dbe.result)});`

or similar - I don't have a playground to test atm

Comment: In other words - do a simple query, no example needed?

Comment: my answer is an example of node.js function with callback to query postgres